CKeditor5 with Angular 18
I've updated an angular project from angular 13 to angular 18 but now my Ckeditor5 does not work anymore, I could not find anything related to it on the Ckeditor5 website, there is a quick start that shows a step-by-step with a standalone component, but it doesn't work on my project. How can I make it work on Angular 18?

I tried to follow the quick start but it didn't work for me

Try upgrading the version to below.
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^8.0.0",
"ckeditor5": "^42.0.1",

Then remove .angular, node_modules and package-lock.json and do an npm install.
Then try to check.

It worked for me thanks a lot mate.
